# Nitrous IO server - Can not search in whole application in nitrous box - Find in Folder option missing

Tags: nitrousio

I am not finding any way to search in whole application in my nitrous box. Basically I am looking for "Find in Folder" search option using which I can search for any string in my whole app.

Also I am not able to open a particular file. In sublime we use to open any view file using 
CTRL + P.

Let me know if anyone of you has any idea or these features are not present in nitrous box

Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the IDE is very basic for now, so you can't simply open files with shortcuts, you need to use the folder tree...

About the "find in folder" feature, you can you use `grep` command as a workaround... example: `$ grep "redeem reward" /home/tom/*.txt` This is not really efficient, since you can't invoke the IDE from the terminal... but at least you can find what you are looking for...

Hope this helps.